# how to extract digit from string in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have one variable in xslt .It has value `/photo/12345.text` .I want to extract `12345` from given variable .do we have any function something like `lastIndex` or `split` in xslt so that I will extract this value from this string

here is my code
 http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLq/2

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:variable name="var1" select="'/photo/12345.text'"/>
    <xsl:value-of  select="$var1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**expected out**
a variable which has value "12345"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(tokenize($var1, '/')[last()], '.')"/>
```

to get `12345`.

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLq/4

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0 (the question is tagged as both?) you can use `translate()`...

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($var1,translate($var1,'0123456789',''),'')"/>
```

Example: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLq/6